# Problems with build without SonarQube parameter

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have SonarQube integration with Jenkins.
All works fine, but time to time the problem arises on one of the projects.
If we start build without sonarCube parameter, it can be failed with errors:

CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\TEMP.sonarqube.static\csharp_1.13.0\SonarAnalyzer.zip\SonarAnalyzer.CSharp.dll' could not be found

CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\TEMP.sonarqube.static\csharp_1.13.0\SonarAnalyzer.zip\SonarAnalyzer.dll' could not be found

The configuration sections in the projects are identical.
In what could be the problem and in which direction to dig?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate on what "SonarQube parameter" you're referring to.

Comment: It means starting build with parameters in Jenkins, where we can choose sonarQube.